# How to add a letter in a field using AWK

Tags: awk

I have a gtf file with 100K rows and I want to simply add a letter 'm' to its first field:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTMUSG00000049935.1";
chr1    HAVANA  transcript      3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; transcript_type "TEC"; tr
chr1    HAVANA  exon    3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; transcript_type "TEC"; transcript
chr1    ENSEMBL gene    3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; level 3;
chr1    ENSEMBL transcript      3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; transcript_type "snRNA"; tran
chr1    ENSEMBL exon    3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; transcript_type "snRNA"; transcript_n
chr1    HAVANA  gene    3205901 3671498 .       -       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000051951.5"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "Xkr4"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTMUSG00000026353.2";
```

A desired output would be:

```
mchr1    HAVANA  gene    3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTMUSG00000049935.1";
mchr1    HAVANA  transcript      3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; transcript_type "TEC"; tr
mchr1    HAVANA  exon    3073253 3074322 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000102693.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000193812.1"; gene_type "TEC"; gene_name "4933401J01Rik"; transcript_type "TEC"; transcript
mchr1    ENSEMBL gene    3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; level 3;
mchr1    ENSEMBL transcript      3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; transcript_type "snRNA"; tran
mchr1    ENSEMBL exon    3102016 3102125 .       +       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000064842.1"; transcript_id "ENSMUST00000082908.1"; gene_type "snRNA"; gene_name "Gm26206"; transcript_type "snRNA"; transcript_n
mchr1    HAVANA  gene    3205901 3671498 .       -       .       gene_id "ENSMUSG00000051951.5"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "Xkr4"; level 2; havana_gene "OTTMUSG00000026353.2";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may  use `awk` to add letter to the start of the row. Here `$0` means the entire row.

```
echo "hey there" |awk '{$0="m"$0}1'
mhey there
```

or `sed` : here `^` represent start of the line.  If you want to directly reflect the changes into the file then use `-i` or `-i.bak` flag with `sed` command.

```
echo "hey there" |sed 's/^/m/'
mhey there
```

Comment: `$0="m"$0` is sufficient, the `{} and 1` can be saved.

Comment: Leave the `{}` and `1` as-is. Removing them makes the code 3 characters briefer but less clear and makes it less robust in other similar situations so it's not a good trade off and is a bad habit to get into.

Answer (score 2):

Adding here 1 more way, where not editing or adding character to line.

```
awk '{print "m"$0}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing is better with sed:

```
sed -e 's/^/m/' file
```

Add `-i` to change inplace.  (`-i ''` for macos)

Using `awk`, can do it like this:

```
awk 'sub(/^/,"m")' file
```